# Calculating specific degrees when the sun is below the horizon given 3 other known values

Tags: mathematical-astronomy

Reference: [Types of Twilight](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/different-types-twilight.html)

Hi all, I have a question that I'm unsure how to approach and I was hoping someone could help me.

**

### I'm trying to calculate the time when the Sun is 16.1 degrees below the Horizon.

**

**What We Know**
On October 5th, 2021, the following Twilight times were recorded (as they are every day):

1. *Civil Twilight* is calculated when the Sun is **6 degrees** below the Horizon. That time is **6:29 AM**
2. *Nautical Twilight* is calculated when the Sun is **12 degrees** below the Horizon. That time is **5:57 AM**
3. *Astronomical Twilight* is calculated when the Sun is **18 degrees** below the Horizon. That time is **5:25 AM**

Given the degrees and times above, is there a way for me to calculate what the time would be at 16.1 degrees?

TIA!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: The difference between the 1st and 2nd twilights is the same as the difference between the 2nd and 3rd, namely $32$ minutes.  Therefore, it is reasonable to presume that the relation between degree of orbital rotation and time is linear.  So the elapsed time after 5:25 am should be $\frac{1.9}{6} \times 32$ minutes.

Comment: wow thank you! how do I accept your answer?

Comment: You can't, because I am not allowed to post an answer here.  This is because your question, as posted, has significant defects, re [mathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  While I personally disagree with the protocol, I can't do anything about it.  My *comment* was intended to spur your thinking.  In fact, a case could be made that even as a comment, my response was inappropriate, because it left very little of the problem for you to attack on your own.